# Why is it "Have you got the 25?" but not "Have you got a 25?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

This is from a english teaching video. [English speaking 01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmUm29fc6nI) (see 7:06-7:08) A customer is paying at a shop and the price is **10.25**, and the shop assistant is asking:

**"Have you got the 25?"**

I would expect the assistant would say **"Have you got a 25?"** but instead he said **"....the 25?"**.

Why is that? Is a coin of a **25 pence** not a generic name?

Comment: There is no single 25p coin. UK coins are 1p 2p 5p 10p 20p 50p £1 £2, notes are £10 £20 £50. If I buy something that costs £10.67 the person at the till may find it simpler if I give them a £10 plus exactly 67p in change (made up in any of a number of possible ways). If I give them more, say £11, £15, or £20, they find it a mental chore to work out the change, or, more likely, the till is short of small coins and they would like some more. In any case, the usual thing to say is (e.g.) **the** 67p.

Comment: There is no 25p coin in the UK. You'd need a 20p and a 5p.  So, the indefinite article **a** is not appropriate here.

Comment: He's asking about ***the*** 25p in the price - because he wants to know if he must open up the cash till to give you *(**the**)* 75p change from ***a*** £2 coin.

Comment: @BillyKerr - yes, exactly. The shopkeeper wants (or hopes for) **the** amount of 25p rather than **a** coin worth 25p (which does not exist).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - there used to be a 1/4£ coin in old money, pre-decimalization, it was the Crown, worth 60 old pennies - back in the day when there were 240 pennies in a pound.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Decimalisation came in February 1971, two months before my 19th birthday. Crown coins (five shillings) were ceremonial or commemorative since about 1900 and not used in everyday life.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - true, I think I was thinking of half-crowns. I think those were fairly common. I have a few in a coin collection. Won't try to teach an old dog new tricks though, as I was only 5 years old in 1971 ;)

Comment: @BillyKerr - as a kid I loved getting half-crowns from e.g. kind uncles much more than two-bob bits. When the 50p coin replaced the 10 shilling note in 1969 (2 years before the decimalisation changeover) we called them 'ten-bob bits'. Intriguing to think that the value in today's money is equivalent to around £10 which also is a red banknote.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've [got a ten shilling note](https://imgur.com/dypo23d) - it's almost in perfect condition as you can see.

Comment: @BillyKerr - weird to think that when I was 18 a packet of 20 cigarettes cost about 4 shillings which would be around £3 to £4 now, but with tax they now cost around £12 and a normal colour TV in 1970 cost the equivalent of £3,000 now.

Comment: But this kind of conversation is no longer very natural.  More natural would be for the shop worker to say, "Oh, you want to use cash?  Right, err, lets see... its been so long since anybody wanted to pay with cash... are you sure you don't want to just use the contactless?...."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Feels like you got ripped off letting them change your pounds for pounds; you should have made them change your pennies for pennies, and demanded £1.20 instead of 50p for your 10 shillings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have you got the 25" is referring to the 25 pence that is mentioned as part of the price. Because it has already been mentioned, "**the** 25" can be used. On the other hand "**a** 25" normally refers to a 25 cent/pence coin (any one them). There may be countries where this is idiomatic, but I am not aware of them; certainly in the UK there is no 25 pence coin.

It would be correct to ask "have you got 25 pence?" Even "have you got 25?" would be probably be understood in context as referring to the pence, though in another context it may be understood as referring to 25 pounds.

Comment: Yeah, definitely no 25 pence coin in the UK. The closest is a 20p.

Comment: Commemmorative crowns were issued since decimalization, value 25p, and I did spend a couple once.